# Spondesne Gaiam, tuam filiam (or Gaiam, Lucii filiam), mihi (or filio meo) uxorem dari? Di bene vortant! Spondeo, Di bene vortant!

Tags: roman-culture

I would love to hear what "Spondesne Gaiam, tuam filiam (or Gaiam, Lucii filiam), mihi (or filio meo) uxorem dari? Di bene vortant! Spondeo, Di bene vortant!" sounds like! This is what the bride's father told the groom's father to promise his daughter to the groom in Ancient Roman weddings!

Comment: Are you looking for an audio recording of someone reading it, or? FWIW, it sounds more like the groom('s father) is talking to the bride's father.

Comment: Yes  looking for an audio recording of someone reading it!

Comment: I might be willing to do it, but don't know an easy way of sharing a sound file.

Comment: click play. https://translate.google.es/?hl=es&sl=auto&tl=en&text=Spondesne%20Gaiam%2C%20tuam%20filiam%2C%20mihi%20uxorem%20dari%3F%20Di%20bene%20vortant!%20Spondeo%2C%20Di%20bene%20vortant!&op=translate